# Edited CSS for spacing in Joomla 2.5 (gk league news template) and Firefox is not recognizing any new code

Tags: css, firefox, joomla2.5

Our organization is overhauling our website using Joomla 2.5 including using a new template (gk_league_news).

We don't like how much blank space is between some of the elements, so I changed that here: ([  ] indicate my code)

```
/* Columns */
aside#gkLeft,aside#gkInset1,section#gkContent,section#gkComponentWrap,aside#gkInset2,aside#gkRight,#gkBanner1,#gkBanner2 {
  /* Main columns */
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
}
[
#gkBanner1 {
  padding-top: 30px; 
}

#gkBanner2 {
  padding-top: 27px;
  padding-left: 60px;
}]
```

and here

```
    /* base spaces */
body > footer,body > header,body > section,section#gkPage > section,section#gkContent > section,section#gkComponentWrap > section 
  /* top margins for containers */

[section#gkPage {

  margin-top: -23px;

}]
```

Despite Chrome, Safari, and (surprisingly) IE9 all being fine with this code, Firefox (15.0) will not change what it sees, at all. I have forced refresh (ctrl+F5), cleared the cache, changed computers and wifi spots, but it will not read any of the changes made to the css/layout.css, the template looks exactly the same.

Is there something in there that is specifically tripping up Firefox? Or an error that otherwise slips through holes in the other browsers that needs to be fixed? This is day 2 for me working on this issue.

Thanks in advance.

***Update*** it is only not recognizing the spacing in this one instance, changes made today work in firefox, but the spacing changed yesterday still isn't working.

This is what it should look like: http://screencast.com/t/SSjQ8DwLNvk
This is what it looks like: http://screencast.com/t/X1Or7igQu5Fn

Comment: Have you tried using Firebug or another tool to see what styles are being rendered instead in FireFox?

Comment: Yes, it says that the two banners are a part of that spacing, which is how we tracked down where to change the CSS for the spacing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be related to your issue,  but I had a similar instance of this bug while I was developing a component.  For a while I thought it was a server issue, but when I installed the component on a different install of Joomla, the problem went away and everything started refreshing just fine.  Thus, my solution was to reinstall the core Joomla files.

Since you are not seeing the issue in Chrome, IE, etc, I don't know if a fresh Joomla core install will solve your problem.  But, if you're just messing with template files, you could try installing Joomla in another directory and then uploading the template to see if that install inherits the same problem.